# angular 5 add input dynamicly and send multiple item to server

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

angular 5 project in serever i must recive multible item to save in database ..

in angular side im trying to create a form to pass multiple item ...

i need a button when press add another input for user to add another item i almost done but i dont know how can i keep input togeter i tryied somthing link this but it not work can you please tell me how can i fix this?

my component:

```
export class RequirementFormComponent implements OnInit {

  private requirment: Requirement;
  orderForm: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;

  constructor(private form: FormDataService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.requirment = this.form.getRequirment();

    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
    });

  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }
}
  createItem(): FormGroup {
return this.formBuilder.group({
  item: '',
});
```

}

html :

```
<ul class="eff">
  <li>
    <div>
      <form [formGroup]="orderForm"  class="editForm" novalidate>
        <div class="input-field" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">

          <input class="form-control" formControlName="items" [ngModel]="item"
                 type="text"  maxlength="50">
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is your `createItem` function? You will need `formArrayName="items"` in template and the remaining part depends on what `createItem` returns.

Comment: sorry it missed updated

Comment: can you post your solution as answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Your formGroup has a structure like: (This is not Javascript code)

> ```
> orderForm = FormGroup({
>     items: FormArray([
>        [0] : FormGroup({item: FormControl}),
>        [1] : FormGroup({item: FormControl})
>     ])
> })
> ```

So your template should reflect the same structure

```
  <form [formGroup]="orderForm" novalidate>
    <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input formControlName="item" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

To get the value, you can do `this.orderForm.value`, which means you don't need [ngModel] here with reactive form setup.

Comment: As said in the answer, its not javascript code. You don't have to change your order form, just keep it as is and just change your template. I put it there just to show how your formGroup is structured.